# How to dynamically adjust DIV height?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the following structure:

```
        <div class="div1">          
            <div class="div2">
                <div class="jcarousel">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                           <div class="item">ITEM 1</div>div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                           <div class="item">ITEM n</div>div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
              <a href="#" class="jcarousel-control-prev">&lsaquo;</a>
              <a href="#" class="jcarousel-control-next">&rsaquo;</a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Each item within the `<ul>` will have different heights though I cannot make it work unless the `<div class="jcarousel">` has a fixed height, which is the opposite of what I want. I want the `<div class="jcarousel">` to dynamically change its height depending on the height of the `<div>` inside each `<li>`.

Forgot to say, and it may be important. The `.Jcarousel div` is a carousel and and I have a `next` and `prev` controls. The `.Jcarousel div` should change its height according to the height of the next li to appear in the carousel.

CSS

```
       .div1 {
        height: auto;
        background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% rgb(255, 255, 255);
        border-width: medium 1px 1px;
        border-style: none solid solid;
        border-color: -moz-use-text-color rgb(255, 255, 255) rgb(255, 255, 255);
        padding: 20px 20px 0px;
        margin-bottom: 50px;
        box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.46);
    }

    .div2 {
        margin-top: -50px;
    }

    .jcarousel {
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden;
        height: 700px;
        margin: 0px -20px;
        padding: 0px 20px;
    }

    .jcarousel ul {
        width: 20000em;
        position: absolute;
        list-style: none outside none;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
    }


    .jcarousel li {
        float: left;
        width: 480px;
    }

    .item {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px 20px;
        height: 100%;
    }
```

Comment: why class & id are same?

Comment: I just edited it (removed it). I don't think it will be relevant.

Comment: yes you are correct but i was just saying as a best practice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying some things I came up with the following solution:

I realised that creating in advance an array with all the heights of the `<ul><li>` it responds quick enough to update correctly the height of the `.Jcarousel div`.

JS

```
      <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){


                  // checking the height of the first element in the <ul>
                 var count = 0;
                 var count_max = $(".jcarousel li").length;


                 var alturas = [];

                  $(".jcarousel li div.cenario").each(function(){
                        var height = $(this).height();
                        alturas.push(height);
                  });

                 $(".jcarousel").css('height',alturas[count]);


                 // changing height when pressing the prev control
                 $(document).on("click",".jcarousel-control-prev", function(){
                    if (count == 0) {

                    } else {
                        count = count-1;
                        $(".jcarousel").css('height',alturas[count]);
                    }
                 });

                // changing height when pressing the next control
                 $(document).on("click",".jcarousel-control-next", function(){
                    if (count !== count_max) {
                        count = count+1;
                       $(".jcarousel").css('height',alturas[count]);



                    } else {
                        // trying to update the counter when reach the last <li> element within the <ul>
                        count = 0;
                        $(".jcarousel").css('height',alturas[count]);
                    }


                });

            });
        </script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try the following code mate... :)

```
var totalHeight = 0;
$('.item').each(function(){
    totalHeight += $(this).height();
});

if(totalHeight < 40){
    $('.jcarousel').height(1000);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JHZSF/

Answer (score 0):

You gave `height: 100%` to the `.item`. It means it will set its height to 100% of its parent which is 700px. If you want the `.jcarousel` to be dependent on `.item` remove `height: 700px` from `.jcarousel`.

You also set `float: left` to `li` elements. It makes the `ul` to be 0px high. If you want to fix it add the following CSS

```
.jcarousel > ul:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: I tried it before. The thing is that when I remove the height from    .Jcarousel    it disapears all the content. Unless it has some fixed height it seems it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Please use below jQuery code for set Dynamic height of DIV

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     var nHeight = 0;
     $(".jcarousel li div.item").each(function(){
            nHeight += $(this).height();
     });
     $(".jcarousel").height(nHeight);
});
```

Comment: why in jquery if it possible in css

Comment: Because in question include jQuery tag

Comment: this one seems to work in part. It sets the height to 1286px and I don't know why. My guess is that might be the sum of the height of all <li>'s. Since I want only the current <li> in display (the rest is hidden because we're talking about a carousel). How would you adapt the code to that? Thanks :)

Comment: Please provide next and previous button code so i add my logic there for setting height  Or You can just get display li height while Previous and Next click and set to "jcarousel" Div

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can set a `min-height` to the class `jcarousel`. Like that:

```
.jcarousel {
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden;
        min-height: 700px;
        margin: 0px -20px;
        padding: 0px 20px;
    }
```